# Я сделал гречу «аль денте» / аль денте

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я сделал гречу «аль денте» / аль денте, и была-таки супернебезвкусная она-с.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5#:~:text=%D0%97%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5.%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%3A%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%2D%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%3F

Comment: В латинских транслированных выражениях кавычки не ставятся. Если это бренд, то нужно писать с большой буквы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Страница из [Википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_dente):

[image: рппрмм]

«Грамота.ру»:

[image: нпиипп]

Comment: А про кавычки где?!

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Кавычки не нужны, если _альденте_ обозначает степень готовности блюда. Если это название, то кавычки нужны.